# How to get HTML content of one page from another page c# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 2 pages `status.aspx` and `ticket.aspx`, Inside `ticket.aspx` i have designed the ticket

```
<div id="ticket" runat="server">
....
</div>
```

Inside `status.aspx.cs` i have a `button_click()` function and i need to get the HTML content of the ticket inside `button_click()`

Can i use `WebClient` or is there any better solution?

Comment: you can do it using WebClient to read and then use its response as your need

Comment: Suggestion: Check how `Ticket.aspx` is populating the `<div id="ticket" ...` and use that logic inside your `Status.aspx` page since as mentioned both pages are under your domain.

Comment: There are many options.You can store it in `browser's localStorage` or You can store it in `View State`.

Comment: you could re-implement ticket as a user control, then you can include that control within your page and make it visible at the appropriate time. No need for any webrequests or anything then.

Comment: @ADyson re-implement ticket is a tedious task, i can get the full html content using webclient but i need only the content inside the ticket <div>

Comment: It's not so tedious, it's quite quick to convert into an ascx. And then you wouldn't have to worry about parsing the HTML to find the right div, which might be a lot more tedious! Plus then you have got a re-usable component which you can use in many places in your app if you need to